# How to add native google login for Android in Ionic 2?

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I tried many links, but I cannot find a proper way to do it.

I found this tutorial as best, but still not working:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#3-google-api-setup

In the above link, I did till 5th step. Can someone help me how to implement Google login in Ionic 2 for android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularfire2 it works well on ionic 2, check the setup from the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md)